# How to use reverse ajax

Tags: php, ajax, comet, traffic, reverse-ajax

I heard about reverse-ajax or comets and thought of implementing it in my chat system.

Previously i had to do this stuff.

**AJAX**

```
updatePulls();
function updatePulls(){
        $.post('resource/php/pull.php',{
            latest_id : latest
        }
        ,function(data){
            ...
            }
            setTimeout(updatePulls,5000);   //5 seconds
        },'json');
}
```

**PHP**

```
...

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id > $latest_id AND ... ");
... 
  /*
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){} and other stuffs
    and finally return at every call from client
  */
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Now after i heard about coments i thought of implementing it but can anyone show me how can i do that ? It says about making an indefinite loops and then i come to do this but i aint pretty sure about that.

**COMET PHP**

...

```
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id > $latest_id AND ... ");
... 
  while($anythingnew < 1 ){
     //again mysqli_query and  increment $anythingnew accordingly
   }
   /* 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) and other stuffs
    and finally return at every call from client
  */
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Any help please.

Comment: You'd be better off with websockets.

Comment: But many big sites  use reverse-ajax and also websockets arent supported by many browsers @JayBlanchard

Comment: It really isn't reverse AJAX, you're looking at long polling. Websockets are supported by [every known major browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

Comment: Then whats with big sites like google talk facebook etc its websockets or reverse-ajax ? @JayBlanchard

Comment: You'd have to look under the hood but I'm sure most have moved to a socket implementation.

Comment: you can try https://pusher.com/ or http://reactphp.org

Comment: i got it but still i want to do long polling....how can i `wait` php until i get new information ? @JayBlanchard

Comment: If you want to do long polling show the code that you're having a problem with.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the code it right under **COMET PHP** ..when the `$anythingnew < 1` its making call to the `mysql` db constantly without waiting.....it can cause severe traffic problems....How do i make the php wait for a bit and then do calls to the DB ?

Comment: Use [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: But will `sleep()` cause any issues to `other clients` ? or to the same client doing a different request to same server ? @JayBlanchard

Comment: You will not know until you test it.